# How do you implement a project with many workflow?

Tags: java, workflow, jbpm

I just got a project which I need to implement lots of workflows, and I am considering to use jbpm engine to implement those workflow, so I want to know is their limits which I need to think through before useing jbpm engine , or any alternates ?
Our workflow is something like following:
user fill in the application form  => assistant manager approval => dept director approval => director approval => boss approval.  And we need to customize the task forms and integrate with other legend system.
Is their any workflow foundation like in windows in Java ?
Any recommendation are greatly appreciated !

Comment: check out http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines - These are just the open source ones. Sorry i cant give you much more details on any but that list seems to be pretty vast. In addition there are always 3rd party products like Adobe Live Cycle etc which also provide that capability + especially linked with PDF document management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say; my experience regarding workflow in both Java and .Net when it comes to the core libraries or API libraries was either under-featured or over complicated.

Saying that, I found that in most cases having a table with statuses did the trick. Let me explain.

Have a foreign key in the table which contains your application form referring to a status table.

Have the status table with an ID (PrimaryKey) Column and StatusName Column.

The statuses should include:

ID(1) **Captured** - User fill in application form.

ID(2) **Pending Assistant Manager Approval** - Assistant Manager Approval

etc for all of the statuses...

Have a user table or make usage [Java - ACL](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/site/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/acl/Acl.html) which has group assignments for 
each of the Users vs Groups.

Like for instance, the people / person who has access to **Assistant Manager Approvals** will be able to see the application forms which have a status of **Captured**.

You should get the picture by now.

On the other had I do find the jBPM very useful, but I also think it has its place in much bigger workflow environments.